# Convert columns to matrix

Tags: excel, function, unpivot

I have to convert a set of columns that contains the list of nodes connected to each other in a network. Something like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XjZi2QeF63UGYtVV9KODBaVDQ/view?usp=sharing

I need to convert this information into a grid like structure for better information presentation, like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XjZi2QeF63WkxaTXRxQVVLWEk/view?usp=sharing

Could you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Not able to open the link, screenshot could be useful

Comment: @NEO_mental.. Can't post screenshot.. I do not have enough reputation..

Answer (score 0):

I think what is described in detail here: [Convert matrix to 3-column table ('reverse pivot', 'unpivot', 'flatten', 'normalize')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) should suit, together with filtering to select `0` values in the third column and deleting those.